# Does cissus quadrangularis help prevent or heal a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, tendons

I have seen many non-scientific claims that cissus quadrangularis help heal a tendinopathy. For example:

https://www.resonatenutrition.com/cissus_quadrangulairs_joint_repair.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191011162524/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://www.resonatenutrition.com/cissus_quadrangulairs_joint_repair.html)):

> Today Cissus Quadrangularis is attracting a lot of attention and is used as a supplement in the fitness industry to aid bone recovery and improve body composition (i.e. reduce body fat). It has shown fantastic results for those suffering from joint pain including arthritis, inflammation and Osteoarthritis and many of our clients have found great imrovements in regards to accelerating tendon repair.

Does cissus quadrangularis help prevent or heal a tendinopathy?

Answer (score 1):

I performed a search of PubMed and found no studies for "cissus quadrangularis" and "tendinopathy". Looks like at this point there is no scientific evidence one way or another.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory if there's no data, there's no answer

Comment: After more thought, I agree. This is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Moshiri et al (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12018-016-9207-3) talks of Cissus quadrangularis with osteoporosis and mentions Cissus quadrangularis in relation to Osteobolin-C.

> Osteobolin-C is claimed to aid in the repair of joint, muscle, bone and connective tissue. The compounds found in osteobolin-C allow for the rapid mobilization of fibroblasts, chondroblasts and osteoblasts to the injured area, along with an increased retention of calcium, phosphorous, collagen and mucopolysaccharides. The increased calcium retention results in greater calcium uptake into these tissues, providing the injured or inflamed area with the remodeling materials needed to assemble and heal an injury in a timelier fashion. The ascorbic acid in osteobolin works synergistically with the *Cissus quadrangularis* (C.Q.) (perennial plant of the grape family), as it converts proline to hydroxyproline (the main substance needed for the formation of collagen) which is a critical structural element in tissue remodeling. Also osteobolin-C has been suggested to demonstrate measurable anabolic/androgenic properties as well, since the compounds found in this product are known to also be antagonists to the glucocorticoid receptor [184]. *C. quadrangularis* has been shown to be effective on both ALP (an osteoblastic marker) and TRAP (an osteoclastic marker) in upper end of femur in osteoporotic-induced rats. The biological activity of C. Q. on bone may be attributed to the phytogenic steroids present in it [184]. Also it has been shown that C. Q. can increase and enhance morphology, structure, mechanical strength and both the thickness of cortical and trabecular bone in osteoporotic-induced rats [185–187]. Thus, it may be a potential candidate for prevention and treatment of postmenopausal osteoporosis; however, there is no clinical trial to confirm its role on osteoporotic patients.

### References

Moshiri, A., Sharifi, A. M., & Oryan, A. (2017). Current Knowledge, Drug-Based Therapeutic Options and Future Directions in Managing Osteoporosis. Clinical Reviews in Bone and Mineral Metabolism, 15(1), 1-23. doi: [10.1007/s12018-016-9207-3](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12018-016-9207-3)

Comment: The use in osteoporosis doesn't apply directly to tendinopathy-- were you able to find anything relating to tendon injury?

Comment: @Nate - The paper may not relate directly to tendinopathy, but the quoted text which is within the paper does relate.

Comment: @ChrisRogers-- I'm not seeing a reference to tendons or tendinopathy in the quoted paper. What specific part are you referring to?